# EWS Managed API along with service account

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I have a service account which **is not** mail/smtp-enabled. The account itself is **memberof** a number groups which has full access permissions assigned through EMC/EMS. Now my question is whether it is possible or not to use this service account to fetch the total inbox unread emails for the accounts that it has memberof, without having to assign it impersonate RBAC role or adding a mail/smtp-adress to the account. If so could you please provide a example or at least point me in the right direction.

Comment: In which way you want to read unread count. i mean using powershell or want to develop application??

Comment: I would only like to use powershell to obtain the total of unread items for the inbox of a shared mailbox. I have this working if the serviceaccount is smtp-enabled.